# Converting Proto Enum to Enum

Tags: scala

I have to enums in two different proto files.

```
enum Some {
    OPTIONA = 0;
    OPTIONB = 1;
    OPTIONC = 2;
}
```

```
enum SomeOther {
    OPTIONA = 0;
    OPTIONB = 1;
    OPTIONC = 2;
}
```

They autogenerate into this in one file:

```
sealed abstract class Some(val value: _root_.scala.Int) extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnum {}
object Some extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnumCompanion[Some] {}
```

and this in another

```
sealed abstract class SomeOther(val value: _root_.scala.Int) extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnum {...}
object SomeOther extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnumCompanion[SomeOther] {...}
```

I would like to be able to convert `Some` to `SomeOther` or viceversa seamlessly without having to pattern match.

I really like chimney's expression something like:

```
Some.transformInto[SomeOther]
```

But it doesn't work as the chimney library errors out with the types being ambiguous

I tried to make an implicit class like so:

```
  implicit class EnumToEnum[From <: GeneratedEnum](enum : GeneratedEnumCompanion[From]) {
    def transformTo[To <: GeneratedEnum](err : Error): Either[Error, GeneratedEnumCompanion[To]] {
      GeneratedEnumCompanion[To].fromValue(enum.value)
      ???
    }
  }
```

However I can't quite do that because `GeneratedEnumCompanion` and `GeneratedEnum` are traits.

So is there a way to convert seamlessly between proto enums with chimney and if not how can I write my own generic method?

Answer (score 1):

Checking [scalapb](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/getting-started/), it doesn't seem like there is a better solution besides the ones you already mentioned:

> Since Scala type equality is not type-safe (a == b will compile even
> when a and b are of types that can never be equal), it is recommended
> to use the various isX methods or pattern matching for comparison:

```
// Using isX:
val t = if (phoneType.isMobile) "Mobile" else "Not Mobile"

// Using pattern matching
phoneType match {
  case PhoneType.MOBILE => println("Mobile!")
  case _                => println("Not mobile!")
}
```

I couldn't find any useful example on converting between enumerations on Chimney either.

Doing a generic method might just work, but you'll need to consider using reflection such as `ClassTag` due to type erasure. Consider [checking this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37524096/2205089).

Comment: I'd say in Chimney  it's a bug/missing feature coming from not-flat ScalaPB enum structure: you have `sealed trait MyEnum` which then is extended by `sealed trait Recognized` and `case class Unrecognized`. Enum values extend `MyTrait.Recognized`, so macros would have to recursively travel through all known subtypes in target which they aren't doing right now. `Transformer.derive[Some.Recognized, SomeOther.Recognized]` and `
    implicit val b = Transformer.derive[Some.Unrecognized, SomeOther.Unrecognized]` same with PB to plain scala enum transformations.